# Firebase retrieve Object by Key in JavaScript Api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

**Help:**

I'm an object of Firebase and can not recover only one item from the list because the key is a objectId and the doc api JS Firebase, it does not have a method to recover for me.

Can you help me?

**Controller**

```
var rooms = Rooms.all();

        console.log('All Rooms:', rooms);
        console.log('Rooms length:', rooms.length);

        // New test room
        if (!rooms) {
            var objRooms = [
                {
                    cc: 'Business 1',
                    name: 'Chat 1',
                    city: 'Curitiba',
                    state: 'PR'
                },
                {
                    cc: 'Business 2',
                    name: 'Chat 2',
                    city: 'Floripa',
                    state: 'SC'
                }
            ]

            var objRoom = Rooms.save(objRooms);
            console.log('ROOMID: ', objRoom.key());
        }
```

**Service**

```
.factory('Rooms', function ($firebaseObject) {
        // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array
        var ref = new Firebase(firebaseUrl);
        var rooms = $firebaseObject(ref.child('rooms'));

        return {
            all: function () {
                return rooms;
            },
            get: function (roomId) {
                // Simple index lookup

                console.log('ROOMD:', rooms);

                return rooms[ ref.child(roomId) ];
            },
            save: function (roomData) {
                var obj = ref.child('rooms');

                var onComplete = function (error) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log('Data could not be saved: ', error);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('Data saved successfully!');
                    }
                };

                return obj.push(roomData, onComplete);
            }
        }
    })
```

**Output:**

```
Chat Controller initialized!
controllers.js:117 Object {params: Object, current: Object, $current: extend, transition: null}$current: extendcurrent: Objectget: (stateOrName, context)go: go(to, params, options)href: href(stateOrName, params, options)includes: includes(stateOrName, params, options)is: is(stateOrName, params, options)params: ObjectroomId: "-JxlCvzgbdkQfoA1Of78"__proto__: Objectreload: reload()transition: nulltransitionTo: transitionTo(to, toParams, options)__proto__: Object
services.js:78 Selecting the room with id: -JxlCvzgbdkQfoA1Of78
services.js:20 ROOMD: d {$$conf: Object, $id: "rooms", $priority: null}
app.js:43 Logged in as : simplelogin:2
```

The factory Rooms is a problem:

```
get: function (roomId) {
            // Simple index lookup

            console.log('ROOMS:', rooms);
            console.log('ROOM specified:', ref.child(roomId).key());

            return rooms[ ref.child(roomId) ];
        },
```

[Update]

I created the factory Objects for filter Object data:

```
.factory('Objects', function () {
        return {
            filter: function (objectValues, objectKey) {
                // to take an action after the data loads, use the $loaded() promise
                objectValues.$loaded().then(function () {
                    // To iterate the key/value pairs of the object, use angular.forEach()
                    angular.forEach(objectValues, function (value, key) {
                        if (key === objectKey) {
                            console.log(objectValues[objectKey]);
                            return objectValues[objectKey];
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    })
```

and `Rooms` factory, I edited method `get` and set:

```
get: function (roomId) {
     return Objects.filter(rooms, roomId);
},
```

[Update]
I have a database based in the image:

[image]

I need list object data.

**JavaScript Api**

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/

Comment: Please do not add "solved" in a question title: it will be rolled back by community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should use Angularfire which provides some useful methods for using Firebase with AngularJS. You can find the documentation here:

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html

Now, your question is how to access an single item using it's key. You can do that simply by just providing the url to that object when retrieving either a `$firebaseArray` or `$firebaseObject` (when using Angularfire API):

```
http://myfirebase.firebase.io/blazing-heat-9118/rooms/ + roomId
```

And then pass this url to a `new Firebase()` call:

```
var ref = new Firebase('http://myfirebase.firebase.io/blazing-heat-9118/rooms/' + roomId);

var room = $firebaseObject(ref);

  // To take an action after the data has finished loading, use the $loaded() promise
obj.$loaded().then(function(res) {

  console.log(res); // res will be the room object

  // To iterate the key/value pairs of the object, use angular.forEach()
  angular.forEach(obj, function(value, key) {
    console.log(key, value);
  });
});
```

Now you will have fetched the single room from the database.

I'd suggest reading through the Angularfire documentation thoroughly as it contains some great methods for handling your data.

Comment: I did not want to create factories in Angular to treat data that own Firebase could bring properly for me.

Comment: @FrancisRodrigues Hmm? My answer didn't include creating a factory. The new Firebase() is required in order to pull information out of your database.

Comment: Thank you @Chrillewoodz! I'm closed the question.